# NetFlow IP Spoofing/Reflection Attack Detection

Tags: cisco, ip, spoofing, reflection

Is it possible to detect IP spoofing/reflection attack via NetFlow?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by an "IP Spoofing/Reflection Attack." IP spoofing isn't an attack, just something you can do. Is that what you mean, or are you talking about something like DNS poisoning?

Comment: I mean something like DNS amplification attack

Answer (score 2):

The IP would be spoofed before NetFlow could analyze it, so no. See here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetFlow) for NetFlow info and here (https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA13-088A) for DNS amplification. The attack must be configured such that IP Spoofing occurs before the router, which is where NetFlow is installed. We know this works because MiTM works. The IP would be spoofed before NetFlow could analyze it, so everything would look valid.

Comment: @Bruce No problem, sorry for the late answer. Note that this is based upon a rather sparse knowledge of NetFlow and DNS amplification attacks, so I could be wrong.